# Update state for function that relies on if statement in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it the best way to write the code below or i have to do better!

```
toggleListen() {
    if (recognition !== null) {
        this.setState({
            listening: !this.state.listening
        }, this.handleListen)
    } else {
        this.setState({
            microAvailable: !this.state.microAvailable
        }, this.handleListen)
    }
}
```

Comment: This example doesn't give enough context to share valuable feedback, so please share more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can conditionally set the `listening` or `microAvailable` properties depend on `recognition !== null`

```
function toggleListen() {
    this.setState(
        {
            ...(recognition !== null
                ? {
                      listening: !this.state.listening,
                  }
                : {
                      microAvailable: !this.state.microAvailable,
                  }),
        },
        this.handleListen
    );
}
```